# derived class's virtual assignment operator not being called

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I'm pretty new to C++, and am trying to come to grips with virtual assignment. The program below consists of an abstract base class with two data members, and a derived class with one. When I set an abstract pointer to a derived object, the program uses the abstract version of operator= rather than the derived version, even though they're both declared "virtual." What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Jay

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Abstract
{
  protected:
        char * label;
        int rating;
    public:
        Abstract(const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
        virtual Abstract & operator=(const Abstract & rs);
        virtual ~Abstract() { delete [] label; }
        virtual void view() const = 0;

};

class Derived : public Abstract
{
    private:
        char * style;
    public:
        Derived(const char * s = "none", const char * l = "null",
                  int r = 0);
        ~Derived() { delete [] style; }
        virtual Derived & operator=(const Derived & rs);
        virtual void view() const;

};

Abstract::Abstract(const char * l , int r )
{
    label = new char[std::strlen(l) + 1];
    std::strcpy(label, l);
    rating = r;
}

Abstract & Abstract::operator=(const Abstract & rs)
{
    if (this == &rs)
            return *this;
    delete [] label;
    label = new char[std::strlen(rs.label) + 1];
    std::strcpy(label, rs.label);
    rating = rs.rating;
    return *this;
}

Derived::Derived(const char * s, const char * l, int r)
         : Abstract(l, r)
{
    style = new char[std::strlen(s) + 1];
    std::strcpy(style, s);
}

Derived & Derived::operator=(const Derived & hs)
{
    if (this == &hs)
        return *this;
    Abstract::operator=(hs);
    style = new char[std::strlen(hs.style) + 1];
    std::strcpy(style, hs.style);
    return *this;
}

void Derived::view() const
{
    std::cout << "label: " << label << "\nrating: "
              << rating << "\nstyle: " << style;
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
    char label[20], style[20];
    int rating;


    cout << "label? ";
    cin >> label;
    cout << "rating? ";
    cin >> rating;
    cout <<"style? ";
    cin >> style;

    Derived a;
    Abstract * ptr = &a;
    Derived b(style, label, rating);
    *ptr = b;
    ptr->view();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using `char*`s?

Comment: Without going into details, you're doing it wrong. Read http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/123-virtual-destructors-virtual-assignment-and-overriding-virtualization/ , and search google for "virtual assignment operator". This has been discussed a lot already.

Comment: To keep the code shorter, I tried to remove things that were extraneous to my question, including dynamic memory (hence the char *s)

Comment: Hi Seth, I've already spent a lot of time searching Google (and this site). I've already seen the page you link to.

Comment: Virtual behaviour is only invoked through pointers or references. You're trying to get it to work on an actual object, which it won't do. Also, when responding to someone, put @[name] in your comment, where [name] is replaced by the name of the person you want to reply to (the brackets are removed too).

Comment: @Seth: But the assignment is *ptr = b. If that doesn't count as a pointer, then I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The part `*ptr` _dereferences the pointer to get an actual object_, then calls `operator=` on the object. No virtual method lookup occurs.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't let you override virtual functions with covariant parameter types. Your derived operator doesn't override the Abstract assignment operator at all, it defines a totally orthogonal operator related only in that it's the same operator name.

You have to be careful creating such functions because if the two actual derived types don't agree, almost certainly the assignment will be nonsensical. I would reconsider whether your design need could be served better by an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but in case anyone else stumbles upon it:

To add to Mark's answer, you can do this by implementing

```
Derived & operator=(const Abstract & rs);
```

In this case you may need to use `rs` by casting it: `dynamic_cast<const Derived &>(rs)`

Of course this should only be done carefully.
The full implementation would be:

```
Derived & Derived::operator=(const Abstract & hs)
{
    if (this == &hs)
        return *this;
    Abstract::operator=(hs);
    style = new char[std::strlen(dynamic_cast<const Derived &>(hs).style) + 1];
    std::strcpy(style, dynamic_cast<const Derived &>(hs).style);
    return *this;
}
```